# android studio volley wait for response

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-volley

I'm trying to make an app that makes an API call and get a JSON array in response, and then, after some parsing it returns a string from the API.

Here is the code for the request (in kotlin):

```
private fun apiCall(context: Context): String {
    val url = "https://example.com"
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
    var day = ""

    val jsonArrayRequest = JsonArrayRequest(
        Request.Method.GET, url, null,
        { response ->
            val listData = ArrayList<String>()
            if (response != null) {
                for (i in 0 until response.length()) {
                    listData.add(response.getString(i))
                }
            }
            if (listData.size != 0){
                val jsonObject = JSONTokener(listData[0]).nextValue() as JSONObject
                day = jsonObject.getString("day")
            } else{
                context.getString(R.string.if_there_is_no_special_day)
            }

            Log.d("notification", "it worked: $response, $day")
        },
        {response ->
            Log.d("notification", "error on request: $response")
        })
    queue.add(jsonArrayRequest)
    
    return day
}
```

and here is where I call the function:

```
private fun makeWebRequest(message: String){
    val day = apiCall(this)
    Log.d("notification", "request complete: $day")
```

But when I check the logs I see that the log that is called after the function is called shows first and only then the response is printed to the log.

```
20:23.451 D/notification: request complete: [nothing]
20:23.451 D/notification: it worked: [response]
```

So my question is this: is there any way to wait for the response to come before I return the response?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my function that calls an API return an empty or null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value) The answers there have a bunch of different solutions for how to get the data back from such a call. You could make it a suspend function, or handle the response by calling another method.

Comment: You don't wait for the response, because that would lock up your app until the network call returned (which is slow at the best of times). In your request you're providing ``onSuccess`` and ``onError`` callbacks, that's where the code is to do a thing once the request finishes. That's where you'd print a log message, get your string, call some other function to do something with it (like displaying it), etc